# Некорректно скачивается файл Selenoid

Tags: python, selenium, docker, test-automation, selenoid

Тест кликает по кнопке Скачать.
Происходит скачивание, но по какой то причине, название файла "download"
Использую GET запрос из документации, там отображается файл "download", при скачивании, файл становиться zip архивом

Docker на Linux системе

ОР: скачивается [имя файла].docx

ФР: скачивается некий файл download

[image: Сам файл download]

[image: download в папке]

[image: Содержимое download]

При прогоне теста на своей машине docx документ скачивается нормально

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема

Comment: в чем проблема при скачивании хз (может в заголовках ответа не тот тип файла), но `docx` файл и есть zip архив, вы пытались переименовать его в `docx` и открыть?

Comment: @Exploding Kitten, даже не подумал об этом, спасибо большое, переименование архива в docx - помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

оказалось все просто, нужно было добавить настройку в конфтест:
"env": ["LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8", "LANGUAGE=ru:en", "LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8"]

Ответ был в документации: https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/#_browser_images